# get strong passwrod from user using php

Tags: php, passwords

I want to get a strong password from users with numbers capital laters simple laters and special characters. A valid password like this **example - Ex: Tesing@123**
minimum one capital latter
minimum one special character
The password has more than 8 characters.
I am using PHP.
Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: This site isn't a free write-my-code service and "I want" isn't a question or a problem. What have you researched? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? We'll _help_ you with your attempt to implement what you need, but we don't just do all the work for you, for nothing. I would be surprised if you are the first person to have such a requirement and that nothing exists already. Hint: if you want to validate that a user's password contains certain types of characters then a regular expression may be helpful.

Comment: P.s. please also take the [tour] so you understand more how this site works. You were recommended to do that when you created your account but I can see from your profile that you didn't. These resources exist to help you have a good experience here so please don't ignore them. thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<?php
function password_generate($chars) 
{
  $data = '1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@#$%&-';
  return substr(str_shuffle($data), 0, $chars);
}

echo password_generate(8)."\n";
?>
```